# $\int f(x)\,dx - \int f(x)\,dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

Which is true

$$\int f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x - \int f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x = 0$$

or

$$\int f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x - \int f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x=c\text{ ?}$$

with $c$ some arbitary constant.

My intuition says that 'something' subtracted by itself is always zero. But if we solve each term separately, we can have different integration constant that will lead the result does not need to be zero.

Comment: "'something' subtracted by itself is always zero" -- this is true but you're not subtracting something from itself since the two integrals aren't identical (as you say, they can differ by a constant), so what you're subtracting may be two different things

Comment: this is exactly why $\int f(x) dx$ is the worst notation ever. write $C+\int_a^x f(t)dt$ instead

Comment: "the worst notation ever" ... Meant hyperbolically? I can think of some mighty bad notations.

Answer (score 6):

Neither is strictly correct: the expression $\displaystyle\int f(x)\,dx$ is not really unambiguously defined as identifying some particular mathematical object except when the context makes it clear.  When it has a precisely defined meaning, it's because of the context that it's precisely defined.

If you mean "What do you get when you subtract an antiderivative of $f$ from another antiderivative of $f$?", then the answer is that you get a constant, or in some cases (where the domain is not connected) a piecewise constant.

This problem comes up sometimes when integrating by parts.  One has
$$
\int \text{whatever} \,dx = \int u\,dv = uv - \int v\,du = (\text{some expression}) - 4\cdot\int\text{same thing}\,dx
$$
where "same thing" mean the very same integral that is expressed on the extreme left above as $\displaystyle\int\text{whatever}\,dx$.  So we add $\displaystyle 4\cdot\int\text{same thing}\,dx$ to both sides, getting
$$
5\int\text{whatever}\,dx = (\text{some expression}) + \text{constant}.
$$
Here the $\text{“}\cdots+\text{constant''}$ cannot be dispensed with.

This occurs in one commonplace method of integrating the cube of the secant function, and in things like $\displaystyle\int e^{ax}\cos(bx)\,dx$.

Answer (score 5):

$\int f(x)\, dx$ generally means the set of all anti-derivatives of $f(x)$.

If you have a set $A$ and a set $B$ then in this context $A-B$ should be interpreted as $\{a-b:\ a\in A, \ b\in B\}$.

Therefore, $\int f(x)\, dx - \int f(x)\, dx = \mathbb R$ (assuming we are talking about real integrable functions). The resulting subtraction is whatever set the "$C$" in the "$+C$" is allowed to come from, as this is the set of all $a-b$ with $a$ and $b$ both antiderivatives of $f(x)$.

But this is more of a question about ambiguity of definitions. You should avoid writing this in practice, if at all possible.

Comment: i think i got it. what if i see it as infinity - infinity?

Comment: @user147078 Infinity is neither a function nor a real number.

Answer (score 1):

You can combine to get $\int (f(x)-f(x))dx= \int 0 dx=C$.

Comment: Why is this downvoted?

Comment: @WillFisher, it's already clearly stated in the OP, as it stands, this doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @ZainPatel Could you please elaborate? The OP asked which is valid, $\int f(x)\,dx - \int f(x)\,dx = 0$ or $\int f(x)\,dx - \int f(x)\,dx=c$. My answer is that it must be the latter because we know $\int f(x)dx + \int g(x) dx=\int (f(x) + g(x)) dx$, and by following this we get a result of $C$. I don't see where the problem is.

Comment: The problem, in my opinion, is that this doesn't get at the core of the issue: what is $\int f(x) \ dx$?